# How do I render my date field using my custom date format?

Tags: 7, entities, datetime

I have a content type with two "date and time" fields, configured to display in "22 November 2012 5:19pm" format:

[image: date fields in Drupal]

On the item itself, the start and end dates are both set to include times:

[image: saved start and end date in Drupal]

In my node.tpl.php, I output the two fields:

```
print drupal_render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_date'));
print drupal_render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_end_datetime'));
```

However, the two fields are displayed without the time:

> **Start Date and Time**: 02 December 2012
>
> **End Date and Time**: 02 December 2012

How do I output these two fields using my custom date format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the node template you should be able to output your dates with your selected format by doing:

```
print render($content['field_date']);
print render($content['field_end_datetime']);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use [field_view_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) for formatting date, pass **$display** parameter as defined below:

```
$display = array('settings' => array('format_type' => 'medium'));
$output = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_date_time', $display);
```

*format_type* - is any valid date-time format name, defined in admin/config/regional/date-time of your drupal site.

Comment: I wonder how to strip all rendering html and label, just showing plain output only.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use [`field_view_value()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) to just show the formatted value.

Similar question which may be of use here:

[How do I render a field value including its format?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/how-do-i-render-a-field-value-including-its-format)

Comment: Hi Kate: I tried `$fields = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_date'); $output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_date', $fields[0]); print render($output);`, but that prints the same string as before (missing the time), just also missing the label.

Answer (score 1):

I used this to create and render the date without a label.

```
$display = array('settings' => array('format_type' => 'medium'),'label'=>'hidden');
$output = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_date', $display);
print render($output);
```

Then you can subsitute the machine name for your custom date format where it says 'medium'.