# Changing date format in node template

Tags: 7, nodes, theming, datetime

I have a content type called news which I created a template for, node--news.tpl.php. In my template, I call the date field as follows:

```
<?php print render($content['field_news_date']);  ?>
```

It displays like so:

> 05/01/2015 - 15:25

I would like it to look like this:

> 1 May 2015

I need to be able to do so solely through the node template, as making changes directly in Drupal will affect other sites and that is not an option. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: there are a couple of options here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51108/how-do-i-render-my-date-field-using-my-custom-date-format

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need a specific template, you could also use template.php. This is the preferred method to keep logic out of the template.

Using template.php, you can do a [template_preprocess_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7)

This [overview](http://www.digett.com/blog/01/18/2012/change-output-single-field-drupal-7-nod3) does a nice job walking you through altering the date. Also, using php date() function you can alter the field to display as `1 May 2015` using `l M Y`