# Render fields in a custom bean.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I have a custom tpl for bean block called: `block--bean--image-footer-block.tpl.php`, also I have custom tpl for both fields:

```
field--title-field--footer-block.tpl.php
field--field-block-footer-imagen--footer-block.tpl.php
```

I don't want to use the default `<?php print render($content); ?>`

But If I try to use

```
<?php print render ($content['field_block_footer_imagen']); ?>
```

or

```
<?php print render ($content['title_field']); ?>
```

I get this error

```
Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in
```

The beans fields are:

```
title_field
field_block_footer_imagen
```

Any idea to print both fields?

Thanks

Oskar

Answer (score 2):

*Note, to avoid getting the 'pass by reference' error, assign the output to a variable before passing it in as an argument to the `render()` or `drupal_render()` functions*

**Partial Solution, without preserving display settings**

For reference, I tried:
[How do I render a field value including its format?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/how-do-i-render-a-field-value-including-its-format)

Which gave me something similar to:

```
<?php
$banner = field_view_field('bean', $bean, 'field_banner_image')
echo render($banner);
?>
```

The only problem being that it was ignoring my output display formatting I had set on the block type. You can specify one, but I couldn't find a source readily available with the values of the `$display` array which would be passed as 4th parameter to `field_view_field`.

**Full solution, preserving display settings**

Since I wanted to preserve the setting specified by the configuration of the field, and not rely on display defaults (ie: showing the label above an image) I looked back at the `bean.tpl.php`. Within the content they were building the $elements array, and using drupal_render. Giving this a shot and it worked:

```
<?php
$banner = $elements['field_banner_image'];
echo drupal_render($banner);
?>
```

This also preserved my removal of the field label.

This was all done within my **bean--banner.tpl.php** which should be a similar setup to what you're facing. Hope this helped!