# How can I print the value of the node body using PHP with the text format applied?

Tags: nodes

I am printing the node body using PHP on an admin view via a template; however, when I do this, the text comes out as one giant block (spacing is ignored).  However, when I go to edit the node, the content is spaced properly.

My code looks like this:

```
print "Body: " . $body[0]['value'];
```

What do I need to change to make sure the spacing/formatting is printed out properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `check_markup()` function:

> Runs all the enabled filters on a piece of text.
>
> Note: Because filters can inject JavaScript or execute PHP code, security is vital here. When a user supplies a text format, you should validate it using filter_access() before accepting/using it. This is normally done in the validation stage of the Form API. You should for example never make a preview of content in a disallowed format.

E.g.

```
$markup = check_markup($body[0]['value'], $body[0]['format']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this drupal default function "field_view_field()".

For this to be done you just need to load that particular node by its node id

```
<?php
$node = node_load(10);
$display = array('type' => 'full_html');
 $output = field_view_field('node', $node, 'body', $display);
 print render($output);

?>
```

$display can have option full_html/filtered_html etc. 
You can apply more options to the display options to print it in desired format.
You can refer this link [Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/how-do-i-render-a-field-value-including-its-format)

Answer (score 0):

depending on the template and the preprocess, but try `render($body)`