# Choosing a display format & printing a field in html.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming, entities

First question ever here... I'm so nervous!

I must display a field (field_asin) in the header of my page.

So I have added this to my template.php file :

```
function theme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $node = menu_get_object();

  if ($node && isset($node->nid)) {
    $node = node_load($node->nid);

    node_build_content($node);
    $vars['field_asin'] = render($node->content['field_asin']);
  } 
}
```

Now, I can print the field in html.tpl.php with

```
  <?php print $field_asin; ?>
```

Yep, it works! But how do I choose the display format for this field?

Thanks!

Alex

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! [This](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/20195/8623) answer should help you.