# How can I loop through a multivalue field's values?

Tags: 7, theming

I have two authors for the same blog, so I want to display both authors details on a page. Below code will display only one because `$node->field_author[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id']` contains 0. So next author value will be like this `$node->field_author[LANGUAGE_NONE][1]['target_id']` So how can I use foreach loop here to display both author details?

```
if (isset($node->field_author[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id']) && is_numeric($node->field_author[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'])) { 
  $nid = trim($node->field_author[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id']);
  $nodeauthor = node_load($nid); //$node->type = 'poll';
  if ($nodeauthor) {
    $nodeView = node_view($nodeauthor, 'teaser'); 
    print drupal_render($nodeView);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you just want to render the author field as it is, check sample code here to [How do I render a field value including its format?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/20195/678) you don't need to write foreach for that. The code which you've used `node_view()` this generates an array for rendering the given node for provided display type.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
  foreach($node->field_author[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $key => $value){
    $nid = $value['target_id'];
    //$key is the index 0, 1 ....
  }
```

Comment: I have no idea why this answer is down-voted.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but typically, code-only answers are bad form (my guess on the down vote); they don't explain why they address the problem, and someone could do something dangerous if they blindly executed code, without an idea of its effects. A simple one sentence here could have easily addressed why this is the answer.